# Как сделать скорость спрайта одинаковой?

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

Начал писать простейшую игру чисто что бы лучше разобраться со SpriteKit в среде Xcode на языке swift. Моя игра просто заключается в том чтобы спрайт(объект) который находиться на экране перемещался в то место на которое мы нажали пальцем, я реализовал это так:

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
        ZombieNode.run (SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y), duration: 1))

    }
}
```

Тут все работает нормально, мы нажимаем пальцем на кнопку и спрайт движется туда, но возникла проблема что от того насколько я далеко нажму пальцем от спрайта будет меняться его скорость, это происходит потому что я реализую это через такое действие:

```
ZombieNode.run (SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y), duration: 1))
```

Тут все логично действие происходит за 1 секунду поэтому чем дальше расстояние тем больше скорость - чтобы пройти его за это время, но как мне это изменить? Мне надо сделать так, чтобы независимо от расстояния была одинаковая скорость. Помогите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно определить duration в зависимости от расстояния и нужной скорости.

```
(вектор расстояния от ноды до location) / скорость = duration
```